# openFileInput(): IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, fileinputstream, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to read data from the device which I wrote to previously.But I am getting an IllegalArgumentException when I am trying to read it.Actually I tried to write to an external sdcard but it has been stored in device storage. I tried hard but could not find a solution to write data to external sdcard. But the real problem is I am not being able to read from the file.Also assigning openFileInput to FileInputStream earlier  gave me a NullPointerException although I have seen many such codes in the stackoverflow posts. Below is the code.Please help me find the error in my code.

Code:

```
 public String getExternalSdCardPath()
    {
        String path=null;
        File sdcardfile=null;
        List<String> sdpossiblepath= Arrays.asList("external_sd","ext_sd","external","extSdCard","sdcard2");
        for (String sdpath:sdpossiblepath)
        {
            File file=new File("mnt/",sdpath);
            if (file.isDirectory()&&file.canWrite())
            {
                path=file.getAbsolutePath();
                String timestamp=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                File testWritable=new File(path,"test_"+timestamp);
                if (testWritable.mkdirs())
                {
                    testWritable.delete();
                }
                else {
                    path=null;
                }
            }
        }
        if (path!=null)
        {
            sdcardfile=new File(path);

        }
        else {
            sdcardfile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

        }
        return sdcardfile.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public String readFromStorage1()
        {
            File dir=new File(getExternalSdCardPath()+"/tut");
            if (dir.exists()){
                File file=new File(getExternalSdCardPath()+"/tut" + "/savedfile.txt");
                if (file.exists())
                {
                    try {

                fileInputStream=getApplicationContext().openFileInput(getExternalSdCardPath()+"/tut/"+"savedfile.txt");
                isr=new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
                bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(isr);
                stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
                while (bufferedReader.readLine()!=null)
                {

                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedReader.readLine());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                finally {
                try {
                    if (fileInputStream!=null) {
                        fileInputStream.close();
                    }

                    if (isr!=null) {
                        isr.close();
                    }

                    if (bufferedReader!=null)
                    {bufferedReader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
                }
            else {
                return "Null";
            }}else {
                return "Null";
            }
            if (stringBuilder!=null&&stringBuilder.length()>0)
            {
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            else {
                return "Null";
            }
        }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/tut/savedfile.txt contains a path separator
                                                                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2663)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:1144)
                                                                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:183)
                                                                                                 at com.globemaster.internalstorage.MainActivity.readFromStorage1(MainActivity.java:190)
                                                                                                 at com.globemaster.internalstorage.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
                                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: You cannot use openFileInput() for a full path. Only supply a file name there. If you want to use a full path then use new FileInputStream().

Comment: Will try that now.

Comment: Could you help me with the exact code for finding the sdcard path

Comment: That is a common problem. Has been asked a hundred times already on this site. So if you google for it you find a lot of answers. Most answers are nonsense. The best chance you have with inspecting the items returned by getExternalFilesDirs(). The second item (if it is there) often points to a removable micro SD card. It is unclear if you want to write to removable media or just external storage.

Comment: A removable media

Comment: There is no "sdcard path". You do not access [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) via the filesystem on Android 4.4+, except in specific situations, such as the `getExternalFilesDirs()` mentioned by greenapps.